# how to get row value of selected column in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

if I return x it will show a franchise_id column with its id and if I return variable y it will show nothing.

```
$x = Unit::select('franchise_id')->where('id', $id)->first();
$y = Franchise::select('case_number')->where('id', $x)->first();

return $x;
```

I would like to update case number in the franchise where franchise id equals to unit franchise id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should name your variables a bit better. Secondly, `$x` in your case will be an instance of your `Unit` model.

You can access then `franchise_id` by using `$x->franchise_id`. Finally, you can use that to perform an update on your `Franchise` model.

Here's an example *(changed the variable names)*

```
$unit = Unit::select('franchise_id')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first();

Franchise::where('id', $unit->franchise_id)
    ->update([
        'case_number' => 'xxx'
    ]);
```

If you just want to access a particular row's value in `$unit`, the following would also work:

```
$unit = Unit::find($id)->value('franchise_id'); 

Franchise::where('id', $unit)
    ->update([
        'case_number' => 'xxx'
    ]);
```

Alternatively, think about doing this with [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).

**Edit**: If you want to check whether `$unit` is empty or not, you can just do this:

```
$unit = Unit::select('franchise_id')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first();

// If there's no unit, it will return null
// which means, you can just do the following

if($unit) {
    Franchise::where('id', $unit->franchise_id)
        ->update([
            'case_number' => 'xxx'
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer.